# Missing my icon color in my universalapp.xcodeProj

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

**Missing my icon color in my universalapp.xcodeProj**
That image always showing as white after installing xcode6.1.1. all options i used here is correct. in don't know where its wrong.

so anybody knows please give answer. its opens correctly using xcode app. but only problem is appearing as white colour instead of blue. please give suggesions to solve this issue.Here iam attaching my screenshot also.please refer

[screenshot](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202481663122213&set=gm.767905009983672&type=1&theater)

Comment: That is way too general a question, vague and non-specific.  First of all, if it's an icon (UIImage view, or UIButton) (both subclasses of UIView), with an image, color isn't used.  Background colors apply to views (not images).  If you showed some code that you were expecting to result in the background color of a UIView maybe we could give you a more specific answer.

Comment: i just edited my question. please see my screenshot. and update your answer "1s and 0s".